# Where the data is Storing in Graphql

Tags: graphql, relay, relaymodern, express-graphql, github-graphql

I started to use graphQl with react relay. And I followed some tutorials and I can able to get and post with the help of mutations and queries. Everything works fine but my question here is,

- Where qraphql is saving the data and fetching that for us

**for example:** If I get data from database mean's I can go through into particular DB/ TABLE. Likewise, i want to know where graphql is storing the data.

i searched many sites, They are telling how to use qraphql but I cant able to find an answer to my question. I need clarification in this area. Can someone help me out with this.

Answer (score 11):

GraphQL is a query language for your API, and a server-side runtime for executing queries by using a type system you define for your data. GraphQL isn't tied to any specific database or storage engine and is instead backed by your existing code and data.

You can connect any database using GraphQL.
As I understand you are trying the mutation and queries with some hosted engines.

Please go through  [this](https://dev-blog.apollodata.com/tutorial-building-a-graphql-server-cddaa023c035) reference and set up the GraphQL engine on your side.

Answer (score 3):

GraphQL, unlike a database level query languages like SQL, is an **application level query language**. It's up to programmer to create necessary logic - in most server implementations realized by using resolver functions - to make a domain described by GraphQL Schema a reality. This includes any form of persistence.

Answer (score 1):

The GraphQL is using localStorage provided by your browser by default if there is no other storage are provided.